# Testing custom validators with injectionpoints, WeldUnit is not injecting the hibernate bean validation factory

Tags: java, cdi, hibernate-validator, weld-junit4

I'm trying to make a very simple testcase testing a custom validator in hibernate bean validation. The custom validator has an injection point.

Junit4, BeanValidation 6.1.5.Final, WeldUnit 2.0.0.Final

```java
public class AssertCrsForOffshoreTest extends TestBase {

    //CHECKSTYLE:OFF
    @Rule
//    public WeldInitiator weld = WeldInitiator.from( ValidatorFactory.class ).inject( this ).build();
    public WeldInitiator weld = WeldInitiator.from( ValidatorFactory.class ).build();
    //CHECKSTYLE:ON
    
    @Test
    public void testValidCrs() {

        // prepare test
        BroLocation location = createLocation();
        location.setCrs( BroConstants.CRS_WGS84 );
        BeanWithLocation bean = new BeanWithLocation(  location );

        // action
        Set<ConstraintViolation<BeanWithLocation>> violations = weld.select( ValidatorFactory.class ).get().getValidator().validate( bean );

        // verify
        assertThat( violations ).isEmpty();
    }


}
```

However, for some reason it cannot resolve the injection point: `org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001334: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ValidatorFactory with qualifiers`. I guess I need to refer to an implementation rather than the `ValidatorFactory.class`.

Comment: You have to tell weld-junit to activate the `org.hibernate.validator.cdi.ValidationExtension`. This is trivial with weld-junit5, with `@AddExtensions(ValidationExtension.class)`, but I could not find a way to do it in weld-junit4!

Comment: ah. .thanks.. that's perhaps a lead..

Comment: adding this to the from clause above helps already.. (I get further).. Like this: `WeldInitiator.from( ValidationExtension.class  ).build()`.. Now I get problems in my custom validator under test.. I guess I need to debug now. More tomorrow.

Comment: Maybe this is the way to activate extensions in weld-junit4. Another thing I came up with and maybe you can try is: `public WeldInitiator weld = WeldInitiator.from(new Weld().addExtensions(ValidationExtension.class).disableDiscovery()).inject(this).build();`

Comment: It works, but I don't know how to inject the mock that is used by the custom validator. But the solution in my comment seems to work and allow for that as well. I'll post it shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nikos described in the comment section above I needed to add the `ValidationExtension.class` to the from fluent method and add the cdi library to the test scope.

This is the full (working solution)

```java
public class AssertCrsForOffshoreTest extends TestBase {

    //CHECKSTYLE:OFF
    // intializes the validation extension and 'registers' the test class as producer of the GeometryServiceHelper  mock
    @Rule
    public WeldInitiator weld = WeldInitiator.from( ValidationExtension.class, AssertCrsForOffshoreTest.class  ).build();
    //CHECKSTYLE:ON

    @ApplicationScoped
    @Produces
    GeometryServiceHelper produceGeometryServiceHelper() throws GeometryServiceException {
        // mock provided to the custom annotation.
        GeometryServiceHelper geometryService = mock( GeometryServiceHelper.class );
        when( geometryService.isOffshore( any( BroLocation.class ) ) ).thenReturn( true );
        return  geometryService;
    }

    @Test
    public void testValidCrs() {

        // prepare test
        BroLocation location = createLocation();
        location.setCrs( BroConstants.CRS_WGS84 );
        BeanWithLocation bean = new BeanWithLocation(  location );

        // action
        Set<ConstraintViolation<BeanWithLocation>> violations = weld.select( ValidatorFactory.class ).get().getValidator().validate( bean );

        // verify
        assertThat( violations ).isEmpty();
    }
}
```

You'll also need to add the cdi extension of beanvalidation to the unit test scope

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I waited for your response.. After all, its based on your suggestion. Thanks for helping out. Seems to be a time limit on it for 8 more hours.